# How to fix octave Library not loaded and Abort trap: 6 bug?

Tags: homebrew, octave

Whenever I try to run octave:

```
$ octave
```

I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/hwloc/lib/libhwloc.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/open-mpi/lib/libmpi_usempif08.40.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

How do I fix this?

Details:

- Operating system: macOS.
- Octave installed via homebrew command - `brew install octave`
- Note- I tried to run brew reinstall --build-from-source octave,

But it freezes midway at:

---

==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/octave/5.1.0_4 --disable-silent-rules

==> make all

---

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I saw some people saying it had to do with `gawk`. I tried  building octave from source by doing `brew reinstall --build-from-source octave` but the error still persists.

Comment: @god_is_love- I tried that but it freezes midway when trying to  do ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/octave/5.1.0_4 --disable-silent-rules
and ==> make all

Comment: There is an AppImage for macOS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `hwloc` is installed by typing `brew install hwloc` in your terminal.

---

If that doesn't work, try navigating to the directory its looking for the file in your terminal:

```
cd /usr/local/opt/hwloc/lib/
ls
```

Look for a similar library and make a copy of it, renaming it to `libhwloc.15.dylib`. If there is a file called `libhwloc.5.dylib` type

```
cp libhwloc.5.dylib libhwloc.15.dyli
```

Comment: So apparently, when I try that in terminal it says "-bash: cd: /usr/local/opt/hwloc/lib/: No such file or directory". So then I went to finder and tried putting the path in, but it only went to /usr/local/opt and couldn't find the hwloc folder.

Comment: @CodingForLife hmmm, try `brew install hwloc`

Comment: and then try `cd /usr/local/opt/hwloc/lib/` again

Comment: Doing brew install hwloc fixed the problem. I'm assuming that I deleted the library by mistake, somehow.

Comment: cool! i'll add that part to the answer in case someone else does in the future